# Adding buttons dynamically - only last button is "clickable"

Tags: jquery, button, user-interface, click

I have this piece of code:

```
$.get(path + "/messages/getMyReceivedMessages", "userid=" + loggedUser.id ,function(data){
                    for (var i=0, dataLength=data.length; i<dataLength; i++){
                    $("#receivedMessagesDialog").html($("#receivedMessagesDialog").html() 
                         + '<button id=buttonMessage'+ i.toString() + '>' + data[i].content + 
                           '</button><br>');
                     $("#buttonMessage"+i.toString()).button();
                     $("#buttonMessage"+i.toString()).click(function(){
                        alert("przycisk " + $(this).prop("id")); 
                     });
                    }
                 });
```

It should be a dialog with buttons and everything works correctly, buttons are added dynamically (for example it adds 3 buttons with text "A" and "B" and "C"), but there is a problem - only the last added button is "clickable", only the last on mouse over has class "ui-state-hover" and has bind click(...) event. Other buttons don't react on click/hover. For example if it adds 3 buttons "A", "B" and "C" only "C" button react on click/mouse over him. Am I doing something wrong?
I will be very happy in anybody tries to help me - thank you in advance.

**SOLVED**, solution:
I should use this:

```
$.get(path + "/messages/getMyReceivedMessages", "userid=" + loggedUser.id ,function(data){
                    for (var i=0, dataLength=data.length; i<dataLength; i++){
                        $("#receivedMessagesDialog").html($("#receivedMessagesDialog").html() 
                         + '<button id=buttonMessage'+ i.toString() + ' class="dynButton">' + data[i].content + 
                           '</button><br>');
                    }
                    $(".dynButton").button();
                    $(".dynButton").click(function(){
                        alert("button " + $(this).prop("id")); 
                     });
                 });
```

I should initialise buttons with button() after loop with class instead initialising it in loop with ID.

Comment: What about specifying the `class="mybutton"` and using `$('.mybutton').click(function(){})`

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan very big thanks, it almost works - it react on click event, but still does not have "ui-state-hover" on mouse over button - except last button which works 100% correct.

Comment: Are you using jQuery UI button? If yes, use $('.mybutton').button() after for loop in your ajax call. You need to configure button plugin for newly created elements in the for loop. `$.get(,function(){ for(..){...} $('.mybutton').button()})`

Comment: Now it looks like it works correctly for every buttons, thanks, virtual beer is coming to you! :)

Comment: Great. I put everything and added it as answer for your reference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a class and apply click, button()

```
for (var i=0, dataLength=data.length; i<dataLength; i++){
       $("#receivedMessagesDialog").html($("#receivedMessagesDialog").html() 
             + '<button class="mybutton" id=buttonMessage'+ i.toString() + '>' + 
                   data[i].content +'</button><br>');
}
 //do it here
 $(".mybutton").button();
 $(".mybutton").click(function(){
    alert("przycisk " + $(this).prop("id")); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try live event:

```
$(document).on('click', "#buttonMessage"+i.toString(), (function(){
      alert("przycisk " + $(this).prop("id")); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append event listener to element, which contains buttons. And specify button:last. It will take care that only last button will be clickable.

```
$('.container').on('click', 'button:last', function(){
    alert('click'); 
});
```

In your concrete situation you can append event listener to dialog.

```
$('#receivedMessagesDialog').on('click', 'button:last', function(){
    alert('click'); 
});
```

Here is the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3ED4j/)

Hope this helps :)